# TimePickerDialog - API 16 Top color

Tags: android

I have a TimePickerDialog.

```
pickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.timepicker, context, 0, 0, true);
```

My style:

```
   <style name="timepicker" >
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/PrimaryColor</item>

        <item name="android:background">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/SecondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/SecondaryColor</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

(Primary= RED , Secondary=White)

How can i colour the white part? Maybe its just margin or padding?
Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library, it will be great help,

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, But I don't want to add new library to this project.

Comment: Ok! as you wish